# How can I put a processing sketch on my website as a a JAVA applet?

Tags: java, html, embed, processing

I have a game with external files and libraries which was made in processing. I want to put this on my webpage as an embeded java applet (not javascript) and I can't find a way to this. Is it possible? If so, how? Thank you.

Comment: isn't java applet known for bugs and security issues?

Comment: @JohnnyAW yes, but my game is compatible with javascript, so I haven't much choice

Comment: @JohnnyAW The bugs and security problems have been fixed, but it makes deploying as an applet much harder. See my answer below.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

Java applets are dead. Most browsers have removed support for them, and Java deprecated them in Java 9.

You **could** use [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html), which basically puts a button on your webpage that launches a Java `.jar` file. But note that you'll still have to sign your application with a paid certificate. Your users will also have to have Java installed and correctly configured. This is a pretty far cry from what most users expect (a simple application that is embedded in the page).

You're probably better off packaging your sketch as a runnable executable. You can do that from the Processing editor, or there are tools out there that package it for you. Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/exporting-applications) is a tutorial on exporting Processing sketches as executables.

But your best option is to deploy as JavaScript using [Processing.js](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) or rewrite your sketch in [P5.js](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/). Then you can deploy your sketch as JavaScript and embed it directly in a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool, to be installed from the "tools" menu called "Applet Maker" by Peter Lager that just do this. Go to "tools" > "add tool" and install it. Then with the sketch opened chose "tools" > "Applet Exporter and Signer". The interface is quite self explanatory.